# assert.istrue returning null value

Tags: c#, selenium

When I run my selenium tests using .net frame and C# I am getting **Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
{
    landingPage = new LandingPageCode(driver);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.Url = ("My URL");

    IWebElement element = landingPage.PageTitle; 

    Assert.IsTrue(element.Displayed);
}
```

My base code is below, which is being referenced within the above `Iwebelement`:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "PageTitle")] 
public IWebElement PageTitle{ get; set; }
```

I also get the same issue when I write the test as per below without the element aspect.

```
{
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    landingPage = new LandingPageCode(driver);

    driver.Url = ("My URL");

    Assert.IsTrue(landingPage.PageTitle.Displayed);
}
```

The landing page base code page is as per below:

```
   [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "HomePage")]
   public IWebElement PageTitle { get; set; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It's almost certainly `element` that is null, and trying to access the `Displayed` property is throwing your exception.

Comment: Can you post the code in the LandingPageCode constructor? I suspect you need to call `PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update: After some research I think you're missing a call to `PageFactory.InitElements(driver, landingPage);`*

Your snippet strongly suggest that `PageTitle` is null. As @greg-burghardt suggests an initialisation method needs to be called on `landingPage` in order for it to be filled up.

Let's try this:

```
{
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    landingPage = new LandingPageCode(driver);

    driver.Url = ("My URL");
    // landing.PageTitle is null here

    PageFactory.InitElements(driver, landingPage);
    Assert.IsNotNull(landingPage.PageTitle, "PageTitle is null. Failed to load page?");
    Assert.IsTrue(landingPage.PageTitle.Displayed);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24268473)

Comment: @NullDev Yes! A very fair comment. I expanded the answer. Thanks for calling me out.